# Find all $(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb R^4$ such that the given set is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonality

$S=\{(1, 2, 1, 0), (1, −1, 1, 3), (2, −1, 0, −1), (a, b, c, d)\}$

My solution

$$a + 2b + c = 0$$
$$a -b +c +3d = 0$$
$$2a -b -d = 0$$

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & |0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 3 &|0\\
2 & -1 & 0 & -1 &|0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ -> $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & |0 \\
0 & -3 & 0 & 3 &|0\\
0 & -5 & -2 & -1 &|0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ -> $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & |0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & -2 &|0\\
0 & -5 & -2 & -1 &|0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ -> $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & |0 \\
0 & -5 & 0 & 5 &|0\\
0 & -5 & -2 & -1 &|0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ -> $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & |0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 &|0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 &|0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ -> $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & |0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 &|0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 &|0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

How do i get the solution if i want to write

The solution is (a, b, c, d) = t(..., ..., ..., ...),t in $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

Just set one of the variables equal to $t$ and then solve the others in terms of $t$. For example, you could set $d=t$. And then the last row of your matrix gives $c+3d=0$, so substituting $t$ for $d$ gives $c=-3t$. You can do similarly for $a$ and $b$. Then when you have $(a,b,c,d)$ in terms of $t$, you can pull out the $t$.